# Android HttpPost Timeout Exception Not Working

Tags: android, android-asynctask, http-post

I am trying to set up my app to throw a timeout exception after 3 seconds on the HttpPost.  I am performing this request from an ASyncTask.  For some reason, even when I give it a domain that doesnt exist, it hangs for about a minute or two and then throws the last exception.  How come my Timeout Exceptions are not working?

```
protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("http://hgfdhgfdhgfdhfgdhgfdhgfdhfgd.com");
            HttpParams httpParameters = new BasicHttpParams();
            HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParameters, 3000);
            HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParameters, 3000);
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParameters);
            try {
                httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
                HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                is =  httpEntity.getContent();  

            } catch(ConnectTimeoutException e){
                Log.e("Timeout Exception: ", e.toString());
            } catch(SocketTimeoutException ste){    
                Log.e("Timeout Exception: ", ste.toString());
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection "+e.toString());
            }

            try {
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                String line = "";
                while((line=br.readLine())!=null){
                    sb.append(line+"\n");
                }
                is.close();
                result=sb.toString();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result "+e.toString());
            }
            return null;

        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't call finish there.

Why don't you return null when there is an exception thrown with a particular error message.

In the postexecute method, do whatever needs to be done when the result is null.

Comment: I didn't mean to keep the finish's in there... I threw that in the last minute jut to see if if would finish the activity on the exception.  I have edited my post.

Comment: @prince what tasks did you move?

Comment: I set all of my catch exceptions to `result = null;` and then in the onPostExecute Called the the `if (result = null){`